# How to upload file in limesurvey

Tags: php, node.js, react-native, limesurvey

Hi I am using limesurvey API to build survey mobile app.
My problem is I can able to use all APIs, but when I am trying upload a file I am unable upload every time it return null response.
{"id":1,"result":null,"error":null}

This is the URL for the documentation for all APIs https://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_upload_file I used same.

Here is my API example params.

{
 "method": "upload_file",
 "params": [
   "tx3yitmq3aqj39g2mbdgprke2hi9brgs",
   323169,
   "323169X48X478",
   "google.png",
   "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAJFBMVEX/////QAAAAAD8/Pzz8/PZ2tr/QwC1JgDxPABJVVdGU1Ssrq/GbyqyAAAAoElEQVR4nO3WiQ0DIQwEwMN89/TfbxLp0kEIEjdTwa4sjLcNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIBfySXPjjBUPSLiqLNjjHNFTy31uGYHGaXG3lJKbY9Vp3j2T8F3xX7OjjJGjvQVa66bEu0u2KLMDjPE+jNc/x0+YJeu/x8+4KbZ1r9LAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD+6wV0kgG++h5fhgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
 ],
 "id": 1
}

Actual API expecting.
**upload_file(string $sSessionKey, integer $iSurveyID, string $sFieldName, string $sFileName, string $sFileContent) : array**

I am passing all params but I am getting null result and file not uploading

Anybody help on the same?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gone through the many documentation finally, Its not possible with limesurvey below v3.15

Answer (score 0):

Without a more detailed error message it is hard to tell what goes wrong. I assume all other API calls work fine?
Did you make sure the file content is properly encoded (base64)?
Also make sure folders /limesurvey/upload/* and /limesurvey/tmp/* are writeable in order to create the temporary files for uploading the content.